# install build-essential on 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04

I am trying to install build-essential on an 20.04. But some dependencies could not be resolved.
GCC is installed. Can not install g++. CC is missing. Seams like no package is broken.

```
sudo apt install  build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way to get the packages, or a way around?

Edit:

Here is the output of apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Hit:3 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:6 https://graphics.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Get:7 https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:8 https://oibaf.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Hit:9 https://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:13 https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:14 https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt wheezy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:16 https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:17 https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease                                                                                                                                                              
Get:18 https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal InRelease [5061 B]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:20 https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:21 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                             
Get:5 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease [2715 B]                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:24 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                                   
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-stenzel/cryptomator/ubuntu focal InRelease                  
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:15 https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core InRelease
Err:5 https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 46B5721DBBD2996A
Fetched 386 kB in 5s (84.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://ubuntu.qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 46B5721DBBD2996A
W: Failed to fetch https://qgis.org/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 46B5721DBBD2996A
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and here there the source:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main multiverse restricted universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://packages.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://packages.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://packages.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://packages.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed universe restricted multiverse main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse restricted main universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main multiverse restricted universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed universe restricted main multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main universe restricted multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sebastian-stenzel-ubuntu-cryptomator-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-stenzel/cryptomator/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sebastian-stenzel-ubuntu-cryptomator-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-stenzel/cryptomator/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list:deb https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list:# deb-src https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.riot.im/debian/ default main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/softmaker.list.distUpgrade:deb https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt wheezy non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/neovim-ppa-ubuntu-unstable-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/unstable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.riot.im/debian/ default main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-tuxedo.list.distUpgrade:deb https://oibaf.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/madlinux.list.save:deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-tuxedo.list:deb https://oibaf.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list.distUpgrade:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntukylin.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tuxedo-computers.list.distUpgrade:deb https://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tuxedo-computers.list.save:deb https://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:# deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sebastian-stenzel-ubuntu-cryptomator-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-stenzel/cryptomator/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sebastian-stenzel-ubuntu-cryptomator-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/sebastian-stenzel/cryptomator/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntukylin.list.save:# deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tkashkin-ubuntu-gamehub-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkashkin/gamehub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list.distUpgrade:deb https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list.save:# deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-tuxedo.list:deb https://graphics.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/madlinux.list:deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/regolith-linux-ubuntu-release-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpak-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/softmaker.list.save:deb https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt wheezy non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-tuxedo.list.distUpgrade:deb https://graphics.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list.save:deb https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list.save:# deb-src https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/balena/etcher/deb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kst-plot-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kst-plot/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-tuxedo.list.save:deb https://graphics.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/riot-im.list.distUpgrade:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/riot-im-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.riot.im/debian/ default main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/softmaker.list:deb https://shop.softmaker.com/repo/apt wheezy non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/madlinux.list.distUpgrade:deb https://sourceforge.net/projects/madlinux/files/repo core main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tuxedo-computers.list:deb https://deb.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heyarje-ubuntu-makemkv-beta-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list.save:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-tuxedo.list.save:deb https://oibaf.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntubudgie-ubuntu-backports-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntukylin.list:# deb http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saiarcot895-ubuntu-chromium-beta-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fcitx-team-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jeremysanders-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeremysanders/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu focal main
```

Lots of PPA installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and also `sudo apt update`

Comment: Did you update package's list and upgrade packages before trying to install the `build essential` package? You may have package marked as `kept back` when you do an update?

Comment: The `you have requested an impossible situation` suggests that you are not using a stock 20.04 install anymore. You have made changes. You have changed or upgraded the versions of certain packages using non-Ubuntu or wrong-version repositories. Those foreign packages are causing the problem. One easy way to cure the problem is to revert to a stock 20.04 install.

Comment: Removing the ppa's did not help. But installed the tools with aptitude (not apt), it downgraded so packages, than I was able to install everything.